# Vector int iterators

Tags: c++

I'm currently trying to run through a vector of `int`s with an iterator. Every time I run through it, I'm only getting a value of 0. Both vectors do have valid data in them.

`OffenseName` and `Down` are private member data that the user inputs.

```
vector <string> :: iterator itr;
vector <int> :: iterator itrdown;
int count = 0;

for (itr = dataOffenseName.begin(); itr!= dataOffenseName.end(); ++itr)
{
    if ( OffenseName == *itr )
    {
        for (itrdown = dataDown.begin(); itrdown != dataDown.end(); ++itrdown)
        {
            //Here itrdown is always coming at 0. The dataDown vector 
            //does have valid data in it
            if (Down == *itrdown) 
            {
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
return count;
```

Comment: Simple typo, `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: if (Down = *itrdown) should be if (Down == *itrdown)!

Comment: While it's tempting to conclude that the assignment to Down was meant to be a comparison, we don't have enough context to make that conclusion. There is still a problem if *itrdown is unexpectedly evaluating to 0, even using assignment rather than equality.

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings. It would have given you the answer before you asked.

Comment: @chris: very good point. I had the same thinking because I usually realize this without a hard to track bug.... but at compilation time.

Comment: @PaulKeister - good point, but there's nothing that would suggest so in this code. "When you hear hoofbeats, think of horses not zebras"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (Down = *itrdown)
```

Come on, the oldest trick in the book :)

```
if (Down == *itrdown)
```

will be correct.

Comment: Cant believe i missed that, but im still getting the problem. Only a 0 back.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in the inner for loop, before the if statement, and check if it's being entered.

Comment: I figured it out. The vector has a value of 0 at the first column. With the break case, it wasnt allowing the for loop to continue so it kept on just pulling in the first value at dataVector.begin

Comment: ...well, now I can't believe I missed that :)

Comment: @Rob: how do you know that without seeing the vector?

Answer (score 0):

`if (Down = *itrdown)`

should be

`if (Down == *itrdown)`

The former is not a comparison, just an assignment, meanwhile you meant second: comparison.

However, there is a more important lesson in here: turn the warnings on when building. If you had done, you could not have missed this one unless you disregard warnings without evaluating them which is not a good idea.

That is probably a more important lesson to learn out of this situation because you would not need to debug issues like this at all then. ;-)